# ZAP Proxy Missing Parameter Exception

Tags: java, rest-assured, zap

I had tried to code zap proxy but encounter errors. This is the error:

```
org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: Missing Parameter
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseFactory.getResponse(ApiResponseFactory.java:50)
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApi.callApi(ClientApi.java:389)
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApi.callApi(ClientApi.java:378)
    at org.zaproxy.clientapi.gen.Reports.generate(Reports.java:114)
    at com.rev.testManager.GenericTestManager.generateZapReport(GenericTestManager.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:390)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:325)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:810)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runAfterConfigurations(TestInvoker.java:779)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:755)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

It point to line generate method.

My code:

```
@AfterMethod
public void generateZapReport() {
    String targetFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    if (clientApi != null) {
        try {
            ApiResponse apiResponse = clientApi.reports.generate("WSM API Security Testing",
                    null, null, "WSM API Security Testing", null,
                    "https://google.com.my/", null, null, null,
                    "zap-Security.html",
                    null,"targetFolder", null);
            System.out.println(apiResponse);
        } catch (ClientApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    webDriver.quit();
}
```

I tried to research on client api reference but no clue on how to fix it. Any hints to pin point the root cause?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: one hint: post the entire stacktrace, not just one line

Comment: Done post the entire stacktrace. Please help to pin point the root cause.

Comment: you might be working with incompatible versions

Comment: Between zsap proxy and selenium?

Comment: I tried downgrade the selenium version but not help. How to enable zap proxy log file?

Comment: API docs are here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/

Comment: You can find the log file in ZAP's home directory: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/what-is-the-default-directory-that-zap-uses/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be passing an awful lot of `null`s

| Name | In | Type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title | query | string | true | Report Title |
| template | query | string | true | Report Template |
| theme | query | string | false | Report Theme |
| description | query | string | false | Report Description |
| contexts | query | string | false | The name of the contexts to be included in the report, separated by ' |
| sites | query | string | false | The site URLs that should be included in the report, separated by ' |
| sections | query | string | false | The report sections that should be included, separated by ' |
| includedConfidences | query | string | false | Confidences that should be included in the report, separated by ' |
| includedRisks | query | string | false | Risks that should be included in the report, separated by ' |
| reportFileName | query | string | false | The file name of the generated report. This value overrides the reportFileNamePattern parameter. |
| reportFileNamePattern | query | string | false | Report File Name Pattern. |
| reportDir | query | string | false | Path to directory in which the generated report should be placed. |
| display | query | string | false | Display the generated report. Either "true" or "false". |

Passing `null` for template is likely the culprit as it's a required field.

Also checkout `reportsViewTemplates`.

API docs are here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/

Info on ZAP's log and home directory:

- https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/what-is-the-default-directory-that-zap-uses/
- https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-you-configure-zap-logging/